# CentOS 7 will not allow SSH local tunneling for port 80

Tags: ssh, centos, putty, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to tunnel the remote port `80` of my `CentOS 7` Server to my local PC through `putty`. Nevertheless, I seem to be unable due to security restrictions. Is there a way to loosen them and to allow the forwarding of the reserved port range (up to `1024`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably blocked by SELinux. The "low" ports are reserved for their use and if you want to bind them, you need to have specific privileges. I guess you will see some AVC warning in audit log, which you can transfer to you local policy using tool `audit2allow`.